# How to show that a given transformation is linear from $P_2$ to a $2 \times 3$ Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm given the following definition for a transformation

$ T: \mathbb{P_2}\rightarrow M_{2 \times 3}\space \space by \space\space T(ax^2 + bx +c) = \begin{bmatrix}a+c &b && 0\\b & 2b && 0\\\end{bmatrix}$

And I need to show that it is a linear transformation. I have done this in the past for more basic transformations, but since we are dealing with a vector space of polynomials I am not sure how to apply the definition of a linear transformation.

Comment: You have to verify $T(f(x)+g(x))=T(f(x))+T(g(x))$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I understand that I need to show that the transformation is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But how do I apply that to this particular vector space?

Comment: How about writing $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and $g(x)=a'x^2+b'x+c'$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Any two arbitrary degree two or lower polynomials will work? Do I compare the resulting matrices?

Comment: How about just **doing** it? Working out $T(f(x)+g(x))$ and $T(f(x))+T(g(x))$ for those generic polynomials I gave, and seeing if they come out the same?